# Converting a binary array into probability distribution

Tags: python, matplotlib, probability, probability-distribution

I have a 2d binary array indicating the presence of half-channels at a particular coordinate (0=not present, 1=present). I need to convert this array into a probability distribution to plot on a map of the globe using matplotlib.

I tried dividing each element of the array by the amount of time over which the values are calculated. For example, if the data was taken over a period of one month I divided by 30. I also tried taking the exponent of each value like so:

```
return np.exp(-x ** 2)
```

but nothing looks right. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: so the 2d binary array contains measurements? if you divide that by the measurement time then you get something like the temporal pdf / cdf for a defined region in your 2d array. Does this help / are you a little bit familiar with stastistics?

Comment: I don't have measurements. I just have 0s and 1s.

Comment: so do you want to perform sth like a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)? because otherwise everything you can get out of a binary 2d array is sth like a irregular chessboard-like grid, right?

Comment: ah, or do you want to fit multiple [gaussians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) onto this "chessboard"? this will return rubbish...